Could Not Generate an Excel Spreadsheet With Multiple Tabs With RLDC in ASP.NET Core
I have an APS.NET Core Web API application. I can generate excel file from my application but cannot export excel file with multiple excel sheet such as sheet1, sheet2.
I want to achieve this as like as the image in below.

Is there any way to generate excel file using rdlc in my application with multiple sheets?

perhaps provide code for how you are currently generating excel files.

you could try using ClosedXML library to generate the multiple sheet  https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Report

@EmreBener I'm just using AspNetCore.Reporting library to generate excel file in .NET Core. It is ideal for generating single sheet within a file but could find the way to generate the multiple sheets in a single file.

A rdl report with sub-reports will output each sub-report on its own tab. You can also break data groups out among various tabs in an excel document. -https://www.sqlshack.com/exporting-ssrs-reports-to-multiple-worksheets-in-excel/

Unfortunately, RDLC reports are not designed for creating Excel files with multiple sheets. Here's  the best alternative solutions:
you can try one of the following solutions

ClosedXML or EPPlus:

These libraries are specifically designed for manipulating Excel workbooks within .NET Core.

Multiple RDLC with Excel Merge in programming:


Create idividual RDLC rports, each creatd to indicate a single sheet.
Export each report to Excel seperatally.
Use a 3rd-party utility or COM Interop (if you absolutely requires) to  programmatically merge the Excel files into a single multi-sheet. This method is more time consuming.


In my report there is some information on the header & footer also with some color annotation. Could I format my report as my requirements using this tool?
